# C# 2005 COM and .NET Access Denied 0x80070005 E_ACCESSDENIED

Tags: c#, com, access-denied, rcw

I am rewriting a C++ app in C# 2005.  The App has 2 components: one out-of-process COM server which can be started by a C++ service.  The COM server uses outgoing interface, meaning it invokes event handler method from the C++ service module upon certain event.

I am rewriting the C++ service part. Right now I have jut developed an app that uses Runtime Callable Wrapper and Connection point to start the COM server and provides implementation for the event handler method.  When I run the app, the COM server starts up fine but I get an exception when the COM server tries to invoke the event handler method of the app.

Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

I searched the web a lot and these are couple topics which closely relate to my problem:
http://www.codeproject.com/Forums/1648/COM.aspx?fid=1648&select=2189754&fr=1792#xx2189754xx

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error during the build process when I was developing a COM interop DLL. I solved the problem by uninstalling the old version of the DLL from the GAC. Then I was able to build the DLL without the E_ACCESSDENIED error.